# Create button in Outlook 2007 message

Tags: html, vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I am attempting to create a outlook 2007 message and place a button within the message. I believe this was at one time possible. However I am reading that this may no longer be possible in Outlook 2007. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use the [OlkCommandButton VBA object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177074.aspx). The link leads to the MSDN site with reference and other useful info on using custom forms in Outlook with VBA.